# Crash when running Cocos2dx game in Android Emulator

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I get the trouble when trying to run the game on Android Emulator. It works fine when I run in a real device, but not the emulator. Please help me :(

The error is

```
02-15 22:20:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(613): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 78
02-15 22:20:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(613): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
02-15 22:20:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:838)
02-15 22:20:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:994)
02-15 22:20:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1348)
02-15 22:20:33.921: E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1202)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which emulator are you using? Android version, hardware acceleration? GPU host? ARM, x86? virtualization enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means your openGL driver is not supported, in that case check your diver details, if your driver is low so update it,

By the way, In first case download latest Updated diver from website, if your are using Windows, type "win+R" open run dialog and type "dxdiag" and press okay, open display tab, and check your details of graphics and download latest driver through Google

For instance:

[image]

For linux, google out "how to check display information in ubuntu(type flavor what you have).

may hope this would help!!

**Edited**

set an Emulator like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm downloading the update. Can you take a look of my Emulator? Is it ok?

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know why. I updated my display above :(

Comment: Are you sure downloded a latest driver?

Comment: I attached the detail driver above

Comment: Download [this](http://www.nvidia.in/Download/driverResults.aspx/71730/en-in) driver .... there are different-different driver version are available nowadays seems you haven't downloaded your particular version ...download this version what i provided you click them and restart you pc/laptop...may hope that would work  :)

Comment: It's not suitable because I'm using Win 7 64-bit :(

Comment: okay sorry, i thought you were using window 32 bit in your pic seems...here is a [link](http://www.nvidia.in/Download/driverResults.aspx/71778/en-in) for 64-bit

Comment: I found out that I need to add this line in the Manifest file, rebuild all and it works perfectly. Thanks
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>